# Linking libcsoap to iPhone project in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, soap

I have an iPhone project that I want to use libcsoap in to make service calls.  I'm having trouble linking a pure c library to xCode though.  I've tried everything short of manually rebuilding the project as an Xcode project.

I built it via command line (./configure; make; make install).  Then linked the output (libcsoap.a) and connected to the headers.  This gave me a linker error saying that libcsoap.a was built for archiving and couldn't be used.

I tried creating a project out of just the makefile but that failed to build.

Can anybody explain to me what I should do to link these?

Thanks in advance,
George